# Filtering certain colors when using a random color generator that is seeded

Tags: javascript, random, colors

Currently, I have a random color generated that I am pretty pleased with.  The colors, for the most part, are appealing and the seeding data portion works as intended.

The problem is, I need to prevent the colors white and black from showing up.  Actually, I would love to omit any shades of white, and any colors that are teetering on being black.

Here is my function:

```
seededColorGenerator = (id, delivery_id) => {
if (delivery_id) {
    return '#' + Math.floor((Math.abs(Math.sin(delivery_id) * 16777215)) % 16777215).toString(16)
} else{
    return '#' + Math.floor((Math.abs(Math.sin(id) * 16777215)) % 16777215).toString(16)
      }
}
```

I was thinking of explicitly picking out the color values and storing them into an array, then looping through them to check to see if said color was returned and if so, call the algorithm again to get another random color.  I am not sure that is the best practice for this.

Any ideas?  I know there are plenty of conversations about random color generators, but I have yet to see a good filtering process involved with them.

Comment: Any shade of white, plus black?  Technically black and white are both shades of grey.  Do you mean to just exclude all the greys from black to white?  Also, is it OK if colours come out close together?  [this](https://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically/) doesn't address your question directly but it may be a good resource.

Comment: That's actually a good way to frame it.  I'd love to exclude all shades of grey from black to white.

Comment: OK, then if you look at the HSV colour space, your constraint is S > 0.2 (or whatever), meaning that the colour saturation must stay away from zero (S=0 means grey, in HSV).  Then you can randomise the other two parameters and convert that back to RGB.  But I don't know javascript, so I can't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you colors are not so many(< 1000), I would suggest use the static color array which can easily filtered to avoid Math calculation for such trivial operation.

Of course, you can use your math to init that array for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to implement a [seeded pseudorandom number generator (PRNG)](/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-JavaScript) and generate three numbers from 0 through 255 with that PRNG until <s>the average of those numbers is greater than 30 (not close to black) and less than 220 (not close to white). This is not the best algorithm for avoiding "white-looking" or "black-looking" colors</s> *`(mx-mn) / (mx+mn)` is less than 0.2 (close to gray), where `mn` and `mx` are the smallest and biggest of those numbers. This is not the best algorithm for avoiding "gray-looking" colors* (since it doesn't consider the complicated issues of human color perception and color spaces), but it may be "good enough" for your purposes. In that sense, adjust the <s>values 30 and 220</s> *value 0.2* as necessary to suit your purposes. See [this article](https://peteroupc.github.io/colorgen.html#CIELAB) for a better algorithm to find a color's chroma (relative saturation).

Note that there are certain issues:

- Unless `id` or `delivery_id` can cover a state space of more than 24 bits (that is, there are more than 2^24 possible values for `id` or `delivery_id`), there are some colors that you won't be able to generate with any given PRNG or hash function.
- Your existing code for `seededColorGenerator` can generate a string of less than 6 base-16 digits if the "random" number it generates is less than 2^20, which can happen at a 1/16 chance. This is because `toString(16)` does no zero-padding when converting a number to base 16.

EDIT (Jun. 24): Edited due to clarification by the asker.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a hex value for a color code? If you split the hex value into three two parts you have R G B.

Then check the R G B components against each other. For white / black they will all be the same either FFFFFF or 000000. Dark colors or essentially blacks will be close to 0 and with similar enough values, you can add an extra check to prevent those values going through.

For example if they are all below 30 find new number. Additionally if you were interested in removing grayish colors, those colors will have similar RGB values also, for example 
A1-B2-C2 is a blueish gray. However as those values approach closer to each other they will appear less saturated. E.g. A1-B2-B2. A little fiddling with numbers and you should be able to figure out how saturated / bright you would like them.

Most of that can be done with if statements or switch statements, little bit of recursion to call the function again to repeat a search for a different color if you wanted.

The most annoying part of this process would be converting to hex, getting the last two digits then converting back to decimal to work with the appropriate values. Someone else may have a simpler approach.

```
x = Math.floor((Math.abs(Math.sin(delivery_id) * 16777215)) % 16777215).toString(16)
a = parseInt(x.slice(-2), 16)
b = parseInt(x.slice(2, 4), 16)
c = parseInt(x.slice(0,2),16)
```

This will give you the three decimal values for RGB. You may be able to operate on them them in their original hex, though I've not played around with that in Javascript yet. You can convert them back to hex the same way you already have using toString(16) then concatenate the string and add the # symbol to the front.

Here's a sample of if structure you could use:

```
#Check for values too close to each other (unsaturated colors)
if (Math.abs(a-b)>30 && Math.abs(a-c) > 30 && Math.abs(b-c) > 30)
{
    seededColorGenerator(Math.random())
}
#check for colors that are too bright or too dark
else if ((a < 30 && b < 30 && c < 30) || (a < 225 && b < 225 && c > 225))
{
    seededColorGenerator(Math.random())
}
#Assuming the color was not dark/bright or unsaturated return it. 
else
{
    return '#' + x.toString(16)
}
```